# powershell behavior of select

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain, why this ( powershell 2.0 )

```
$wmi=Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile
$wmi|select *;
$wmi|select SID;
$wmi|select LocalPath;
```

gives expected results ( selected everything, then selected SIDs, then LocalPaths), while these two gives

```
$wmi=Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile
$wmi|select LocalPath;
$wmi|select SID;
$wmi|select LocalPath;
```

LocalPaths, nothing, LocalPaths

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile|select SID;
"separator";
gwmi win32_UserProfile|select LocalPath;
"separator"
gwmi Win32_UserAccount|select *;
```

SIDs, nothing, SIDs again
Is there only one instance of select ?

Comment: "...while these two" what? What are you asking?

Comment: repaired it, busy night yesterday

Comment: I do not see the same behavior. Copy/pasting into a v2 PowerShell session here produces no empty values. What do you get for `$wmi.Count` and `($wmi | select SID).Count`?

Comment: outputs of all three commands and counts that you requested are here
http://pastebin.com/bQtUzCxQ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a weird edge case of how the formatting of output in powershell works. Please see [this description of the issue from Jeffrey Snover.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx)

I can only reproduce this behavior when running the commands all on one line like so:

```
$wmi=Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile; $wmi | select localpath;$wmi|select SID; $wmi | select localpath
```

This must be (speculating here) because the entire line is submitted to Out-Default as a batch; if you run each command individually, you don't see this behavior.

But with one call to Out-Default, it first sees the Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject with one property, 'LocalPath', so it creates a table with one column, for 'LocalPath.' Once you get some Selected.System.ManagementObjects with a 'SID' property, they appear in the table as nulls, because their 'LocalPath' property (the only one Format-Table knows to display) is null.

This problem doesn't happen in the first example because the 'select *' causes Out-Default to choose Format-List as the formatter, which is much less lossy.

I hope this helps -- the blog post I linked explains it very well.